# JS - event loop execution with 2 promises intersect

Tags: javascript, promise, event-loop

I was trying to figure out what happens with the event loop in the browser when there're 2 Promises. Here I provide my test code and my understanding below:

```js
const promiseA = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve()
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseA - 1')
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseA - 2')
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseA - 3')
})

const promiseB = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve()
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseB - 1')
    return
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseB - 2')
    return
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseB - 3')
    return
})

// promiseA - 1
// promiseB - 1
// promiseA - 2
// promiseB - 2
// promiseA - 3
// promiseB - 3
```

My understanding:

When promiseA resolves, the `console.log('promiseA - 1')` will be pushed to task queue; next, promiseB resolves, and the `console.log('promiseB - 1')` will be pushed to task queue.

At this point since the call stack is clear, it turns to execute the `console.log('promiseA - 1')`, and the next handler `console.log('promiseA - 2')` will be push to task queue, and so on...

So far the result is as I expected. (Please correct me if I'm wrong, thanks.)

Then I want to see what's the difference between returning pure value (e.g. `undefined`, in my example) and returning a value in Promise-based (i.e. `Promise.resolve(value)`) in the then handler.

Code:

```js
const promiseA = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve()
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseA - 1')
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseA - 2')
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseA - 3')
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseA - 4')
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseA - 5')
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseA - 6')
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseA - 7')
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseA - 8')
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promiseA - 9')
})


const promiseB = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(Promise.resolve())
}).then(function() {
    console.log('Promise.resolve() - 1')
    return Promise.resolve()
}).then(function() {
    console.log('Promise.resolve() - 2')
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => console.log('then'))
}).then(function() {
    console.log('Promise.resolve() - 3')
    return Promise.resolve()
})

// promiseA - 1
// promiseA - 2
// promiseA - 3
// Promise.resolve() - 1
// promiseA - 4
// promiseA - 5
// promiseA - 6
// Promise.resolve() - 2
// promiseA - 7
// then
// promiseA - 8
// promiseA - 9
// Promise.resolve() - 3
```

Here comes my question, can anyone explain about what happens in here to me? There seems to be 3 rounds of event loop running when returning the `Promise.resolve()` in the handler, why?

Comment: There are **lots** of questions about this that have already been asked and answered, including synthetic examples extremely similar to what you've provided. Please search thoroughly and only post when you can't find previous questions covering the topic.

Comment: Side note: People misuse the term "resolve" in regard to promises a lot. For what it's worth, I go over promise terminology in [this blog post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).

Comment: *(* Love *the username! :-) )*